# Como selecionar todas as options de um select para submeter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não estou conseguindo enviar as opções selecionadas quando entro no código abaixo.
Fora do código está funcionando.

a página recebe informações e monta a caixa de acordo com os pedidos que vieram, então é possível retirar pedidos e ao fazer isso a tela precisa atualizar para fazer algumas coisas no servidor.

O problema está sendo na hora de passar os pedidos que restaram na caixa para o servidor, nesse pedaço de código eu não estou conseguindo selecionar os pedidos para enviar. No console.log ele já informa que o valor é null.

Estou me referindo ao **último else**, todo o resto funciona.

Alguma ideia?

'''

```
 $("#PedidoSelecionado").on("change",function(){
        $("#PedidoDisponivel").append($("#PedidoSelecionado option:selected").clone(true));
        $("#PedidoSelecionado option:selected").remove();
        ordenarOptions("PedidoDisponivel");
        ordenarOptions("PedidoSelecionado");
        <cfif variables.MensaErro neq "">
            if($("#PedidoSelecionado > option").length == 0){
                $("#PedidoSelecionado").addClass("is-invalid");
                $("#PedidoSelecionado").removeClass("is-valid");
                erro = true;
                mensagem = "<strong>Você precisa selecionar pelo menos um pedido.</strong><br>";
                $(".container-fluid .alert-danger").html(mensagem)>
                $(".container-fluid .alert-danger").show("slow",function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".container-fluid .alert-danger").hide("slow");
                    },
                    3000);
                });
            }
            else{
                $("#PedidoSelecionado option").each(function(){
                    $(this).attr("selected",true);
                });
                console.log($("#PedidoSelecionado").val());return;
                ChamaRotina('Estoque','Pedido',$("#PedidoSelecionado").val());
            }
        </cfif>
    });
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumindo que o seu `select` possui o atribulo `multiple` definido.

Ao invés de:

```
$("#PedidoSelecionado option").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("selected",true);
});
```

Use:

```
$('#PedidoSelecionado option').prop('selected', true);
```

Sobre o `.prop()`;

https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Atenção:

Para versões jQuery 1.6+ temos:

```
$('#PedidoSelecionado option').prop('selected', true);
```

E para versões antigas:

```
$('#PedidoSelecionado option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Você também pode usar uma função para assumir isso:

```
function selectAll(){
    $("#PedidoSelecionado").find("option").each(function(this) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
}
```

Comment: Opa @Eliseu B. Rapaz, eu tenho esse código que você descreveu na página, mas nesse momento aí não funcionou. Eu consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

Comment: var options = $('#PedidoSelecionado option');
var values = $.map(options ,function(option) {
return option.value;
});
ChamaRotina('EstoqueFaturamento','Pedidos',values);
"Obrigado"

Comment: Ok, que bom que foi resolvido, ao fazer uma pergunta, faça referência de versões que está usando, se também existem dependências e assim dá para trabalhar uma resposta no cenário da sua dúvida, facilita, boa sorte.